# Progressing through ADOM's mid-game

Tags: adom

How can I make the most of a run in ADOM?

Here's what I typically do now: first thing first, I go to SMC to lock it to level 1. Then, if my character is weak, I grind a little in the ID 1-5 for a few levels, then I go for either the carpenter or Keethrax quest. Afterwards its UD and D with the pyramid before hitting level 15.

The problem is the furthest I ever made it is completing most of the dwarf town quests with a ratling weaponsmith and I died due to making a very rash decision. Now I died for strangely angering the dwarftown blacksmith (maybe it's because I was an elf). Then there's the monsters: some of the mid-game monsters tend to get rather ridiculous: quicklings that move 5 times during your turn, tension rooms of chaos knights and I sometimes run into monsters I have never seen before, like neutral knights.

Any tips on surviving the mid-game onslaught?

Comment: Your main question seems a bit openended for our format, but you could propably focus it to _your spesific situation_ rather easily and avoid the question being judged as a simple "How do I ADOM good?"

Comment: @DJPirtu Is this good enough?

Comment: Seems better, yes. I hope someone's able to help you with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to play as a wizard.

- Nothing is immune to Magic Missile, and if you practice it enough it becomes very cheap and powerful.  You can kill monster rooms just by bouncing magic missiles through them from long-distance.
- Teleport is a great all-purpose panic button.  If a monster gets in your face, you can teleport down a corridor and hit it with magic missiles as it runs at you.  For monsters with breath weapons, it's helpful to stand just around the corner and *bounce* the magic missile down the corridor.
- For very dangerous opponents you want area-effect spells such as Burning Hands/Fireball/Acidball/Lightningball because these will never "miss".  Note that 32 Wisdom is a sweet spot for using ball spells because it increases your blast radius.

Your starting physical stats will be low, but you can train them up, and by the middle game you should be close to where a fighter would be.

Some of your characters will die in early levels -- sometimes due to traps and low HP, sometimes due to getting in a fight and running out of power points for spellcasting.  Both of these problems will disappear as you gain levels.

Comment: What race would you suggest for a wizard?

Comment: I usually played as human but I don't know if that's absolutely the best. Consider playing a race with a high Learning stat because that's harder to train up after character creation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Magic always seemed really strong in ADOM. I guess it's time to dwelve into the world of dark magicks.